# Why does my Excel function have too many arguments?

Tags: excel, function, parameter-passing

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this function? Thanks so greatly!!

=IF(B4<7500, "POOR",IF(B4<10000, "GOOD","GREAT",IF(B4>12500,"EXCELLENT"))

Comment: Hint: What condition is supposed to trigger "GREAT"?

Comment: IF takes three parameters. You feed it four. That's one too many.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
=if(B4 < 7500, "POOR", if(B4 < 10000, "GOOD", if(B4 < 12500, "GREAT", "EXCELLENT")))
```

Note, this assumes that your B4 values are numbers, so you can add error handling if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lookup function instead of nested IFs. Either store the values in a table in a spreadsheet (easy to maintain) or write the value pairs into the formula:

```
=LOOKUP(B4,{0,7500,10000,12500},{"poor","good","great","excellent"})
```